# Objective-C Conversion Errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a project I am working on. the project uses `AFNetworking 2.0` to get YouTube GDATA from a channel and load it into a UITableView. There was a tutorial I saw by Jared Davidson which showed me how to do so. It was great but the problem was it was in `Objective - C` and my project is in `Swift`. I am currently trying to convert some code to swift but I have stumbled upon a problem.

I tried converting this,

```
self.post = self.posts[@"data"][@"items"];
```

To this in swift,

```
self.post = self.posts["data"]["items"] as NSMutableDictionary
```

But I get an error which says...

> 'AnyObject?' does not have a member named 'subscript'

I have tried numerous ways to fix it but I still don't know how to do it. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks
!

Comment: Instead of wondering, why not learn Swift before you try to write Swift code? These are very basic things you are asking about!

Comment: "I know alot about swift" I don't think you do. "It's just these things I haven't learnt partly because I have never seen tutorials on them" Well, here's mine, which would have answered your question about dictionaries: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_dictionary

Comment: @matt Your tutorial includes the explanation of completely meaningless compiler errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing a dictionary returns an optional since the key may not exist..  This is how the compiler parses it:

1. Call `posts`.  Returns an `NSDictionary`.
2. Call `subscript` on the returned object, with an argument of "data."  Returns an optional `AnyObject`.
3. Call `subscript` on the returned `AnyObject?`, with an argument of 'data'.  This causes an error, because you need to unwrap it.

You need to change it to:

```
self.post = self.posts["data"]!["items"] as NSMutableDictionary
```

Now this is what happens:

1. Call `posts`.  Returns an `NSDictionary`.
2. Call `subscript` on the returned object, with an argument of "data."  Returns an optional `AnyObject`.
3. Unwrap the optional.  Returns an `AnyObject` (not optional).
4. Call `subscript` on the returned `AnyObject`, with an argument of 'data'.
5. Cast it to an `NSMutableDictionary`.  I believe a cast also unwraps it.
6. Call `setPost` with the result.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responce! It works great but when I run my app it crashes and says fatal error... What's wrong? It it this line of code? `self.posts = (responceObject : NSDictionary())`

Comment: @Jesster2k10 `self.posts = (responceObject : NSDictionary())` should be `self.posts = responceObject as NSDictionary`.